# Best method to download remote files

Tags: php

I've been trying to find the best method to download large files from other servers using PHP , but seems i am failing in that or i am not fully satisfied .

so my question is , what is the fastest method that uses less ram to download large files ? is it curl ? of fopen ? and if it was fopen , what strategy to use ?

Thank you .

Comment: Are you downloading to process the files in PHP, or just downloading so they're stored somewhere. If it's just to download for storage, then exec wget externally and let that run in the background, which removes PHP from the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest would probably be using sockets, but that would be like inventing the wheel again.
You should indeed use cURL. I found this snippet online, so that you dont use all your memory:

```
set_time_limit(0);

$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.ext', 'w+'); // Output file
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/largefile.ext'); // Input file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

*Source: http://www.webdigity.com/index.php?action=tutorial;code=45*

Answer (score 1):

fopen is not reliable in that it requires you to have allow_url_fopen enabled (it's usually disabled due to security concerns).  You have far more options with cURL than you do with fopen.